# How to get @Qualifier from each bean of @Autowired List<> in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

Is there any way to get `@Qualifier` name from each bean of `@Autowired List<Bean>` in Spring. Or more broadly: Can i get a Bean `@Qualifier` information at runtime if i have a bean instance?

Lets suppose i have:

```
//Config.java
@Bean(name = "en-db")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.en")
public DataSource dataSourceEN() {...}

@Bean(name = "de-db")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.de")
public DataSource dataSourceDE() {...}

//Repository.java
public Repository(List<DataSource> ds) { 
    // Is there any way to create a hashmap of Qualifier => Bean? 
    // like {"en-db" : ds.get(0), "de-db" : ds.get(1)}
    // or maybe there is a way to autowire the Hashmap<Qualifier, Bean>
}
```

right now i'm using this (and it works fine):

```
public Repository(@Qualifier("en-db") DataSource en, 
                  @Qualifier("de-db") DataSource de, //... and many more  
){ 
   Map<String, EntityManager> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
   dataSources.put("en-db", en);
   dataSources.put("de-db", de);
   ...

}
```

But i have 10+ data sources and it feels that there should be some way to detect the Bean Qualifier even after autowire and i can just use @Autowired List.

PS: it is not a localisation issue, i'm using all 10 db on a single page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a bean 's  most detailed metadata information , your best bet is to inject `DefaultListableBeanFactory` and play around its API .

But your case (i.e Get a map for certain type of bean keyed by its beanName) can be simply achieved by injecting `ApplicationContext` and call its  `getBeansOfType`:

```
@Autowired
public Repository(ApplicationContext ctx) { 
   //The key is the beanName which is en-db , de-db .....  
   Map<String, DataSource> map = ctx.getBeansOfType(DataSource.class);
}
```

Or better yet is to inject `Map<String, DataSource>`  :

```
public class Repository {

   @Autowired
   private Map<String, DataSource> dataSources;

}
```

Comment: Heh, thx after your answer it looks like my problem is a bit more complicated, but you answer is correct. My actual bean is `EntityManager`, but i have `@Bean(name = "en") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fn()` in my config with Qualifiers, so when i give `@Qualifier("en") EntityManager en` to constructor it actually looks for `FactoryBean` name and gives me the correct EntityManager. But when i  `@Autowired   Map<String, EntityManager> ems;`  they don't have qualifiers, so the key is something like `org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0`

Comment: @varren, Your question seem interesting. If you are still no luck on it , let open a new question for it and i am happy to look at it :D